# What kind of mittens is Les Stroud wearing?

Tags: gear

What kind of mittens is [Les Stroud](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Les_Stroud) wearing? Is there a name for them? I'm interested to find out about them and what it costs for a pair. [image: mittens]

Comment: my guess would be sealskin, locally made. You see the leather part and the fur is inside.

Comment: @KateGregory - Yeah, sealskin makes sense. I wonder if there's a particular name used for mittens like this? Perhaps they just go by "mittens." :)

Comment: "Gauntlet extreme-cold mittens" is the style of mitten. They're popular in Canada, It's common to make them out of sheepskin. Couldn't tell you what his are made out of though.

Comment: @ShemSeger - Most excellent! Thank you. And...be careful ice climbing. You know we all worry about you.